# What is Watson's "old service" in "His Last Bow"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, arthur-conan-doyle, sherlock-holmes

I’d like to ask about a sentence in "[His Last Bow](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/His_Last_Bow.-_The_War_Service_of_Sherlock_Holmes)" by Arthur Conan Doyle.

> As to you, Watson, ***you are joining us with your old service***, as I
> understand, so London won’t be out of your way.

I can’t exactly tell what the speaker Holmes means by the line above, especially about his use of the word “service”.
It certainly isn’t about military service, is it?  So what’s this?
They are taking a man to the Scotland Yard here, so is this “service” old friends in the police force like Lestrade, Hopkins and some others? (I don’t think they were there though, for the setting of this episode is way later than when Holmes was an active consulting detective in London) .
Or maybe this “service” doesn’t refer to any organization or society, but a quality of someone’s character or something? By this line, is Holmes’ saying something like “you were a good sport, my devoted assistant, friend-helping guy, so of course you’re coming along with me like a good sport, your old self right?”   I don’t know.
Could someone paraphrase this please?

Answer (score 12):

It transpires that part of the confusion with this sentence arises from a difference in the text between the first UK publication in the Strand magazine of September 1917 and the later collected stories as published in book form.

The Strand edition says (my emphasis)

> 'you are joining *up* with your old service'

[image]

The story takes place on the 2nd of July 1914, less than a week after the assassination of Archduke Ferdinand. Britain stood on the brink of officially declaring itself at War with Germany.

Dr Watson had been an Army Surgeon in India and in the second Anglo-Afghan war, so 'joining up with his old service' simply means rejoining the Army Medical Corps. he is likely doing this in anticipation of the army requiring the 'old hands' of wartime surgeons in view of what is to come.

Dr Watson's previous military attachment was to the 66th (Berkshire) Regiment of Foot, which by 1914 had been amalgamated into the Royal Berkshire Regiment who were garrisoned in Reading. As the story is set in either Suffolk or Essex (the lights of Harwich can be seen which limits the possibilities), Watson would be likely to go through London if he were headed there, hence Holmes' statement about London not being 'out of [his] way'.

The form of 'joining us with your old Service' has been continued into many editions, including the Gutenberg text, but on balance, the legibility and clear meaning of the original version gives no reason to suppose that the change from the Strand edition was intended to be a correction rather than a typographical error in its own right.

I am much indebted to Alexis Barquin at the [Arthur Conan Doyle encyclopedia](https://www.arthur-conan-doyle.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) for a swift response to my enquiry on this matter and for their inclusion of the scan from the Strand Magazine.

Comment: [Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2350/2350-h/2350-h.htm) also has "joining *us*".

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes I've just checked a few sources on Google books and everyone does seem to have 'join us'. I still think 'join up' makes for the better sentence, but if typo it is, it is of very long standing and my theory probably bites the dust!

Comment: I've dropped an email to the contact email address on the Arthur Conan Doyle Encyclopedia website to ask if they can comment on their text's variance from other published sources.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I had a response! See edited answer

Comment: Nice! I can't upvote again, but my ambivalent upvote has now become an enthusiastic upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks for the trouble really. I just thought it couldn't have meant to be military when I first saw the line since both Holmes and Watson were too old (about 60 years old then) for that, but now I'm for the the idea where the word actually meant his old service, military. Holmes must not have meant this in official sense but just told Watson to give them some support or even just be my helping hand for some time like you did before.

Comment: Just because Holmes told Watson something like "it may be the last quiet talk that we shall ever have” in little ago in the plot, I thought they will part soon, but it must've meant they can't have quiet talk because war was coming, maybe. So anyway, thanks very much.